# The output of my list of lists makes no sense. using .pop and .insert

Tags: python, list, tkinter

if you run this small GUI, and insert a few examples (q1, a1, h1) hit "save/next" (q2, a2, h1,) save/next (q3, a3, h3) save/next. 
then click the edit/confirm save Button.
it'll bring the first (q1, a1, h1) Change some of the contents to ex: (question 1, answer 1, hint 1) hit "save Entry #0" button.
it saves it at the correct place [[0][]] which is list[item0]. now the next edit, change contents to (question 2, answer 2, hint 2)
Then hit "save Entry #1" again. This is where i need help. The print output i used to debug shows that both the list item [[0][1]] zero and one
have both been changed with the item that was supposed to be in list 1 only. and then i lose the stuff in list 0. Why could this be??

```
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
n=0
x = 10
y = 10
single_questions = []
all_questions = []
# clear all the entries or Text
def clear(event=None):
    l = [Quest_Entry, Ans_Entry, Hint_Entry]
    for i in l:
        i.delete(1.0, 'end')

# add single questions to all questions
def add_to_all_questions(new_list):
    print ("appending : " + str(list(new_list)))
    all_questions.append(list(new_list))
# saves single questions, call add_to_all_question and clears screen.  
def save_next(event=None):
    l = [Quest_Entry, Ans_Entry, Hint_Entry]
    for i in l:
        single_questions.append(i.get(1.0,'end').strip())
    clear()
    Quest_Entry.focus()
    add_to_all_questions(single_questions)
    single_questions.clear()
# first method of button check confirm
def check_confirm(event=None):
    ''' should disappear after initiation and set back to n=0'''
    global n
    print ("Confirm btn pressed")
    save_next.configure(state="disabled")
    confirm_btn.grid_forget()
    confirm.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)
    clear()
    n=0
    Incrementer()
# Increment then display the following questions
def Incrementer(event=None):
    global n
    root.update_idletasks()

    if n < len(all_questions):
        Quest_Entry.insert(1.0,all_questions[n][0])
        Ans_Entry.insert(1.0,all_questions[n][1])
        Hint_Entry.insert(1.0,all_questions[n][2])
        confirm.configure(text="Save Entry #{}".format(n))

    else:
        Quest_Entry.insert(1.0, "No more Entries Click \
Main to close course or back to return to options.")
        save_next.configure(state="normal")
        confirm.configure(state="disabled")
        return
# confirm what's being displayed and save new changes
def save_new_confirm(event=None):
    global n
    l = [Quest_Entry, Ans_Entry, Hint_Entry]
    print ("currently editing list index {} ".format(n))
    print ("before list")
    for i in range(len(all_questions)):
        print ("list # {}".format(i))
        for x in all_questions[i]:
            print ("\titem: {}".format(x))
print("clearing {} from single question".format(single_questions))
single_questions.clear()
for i in l:
    single_questions.append(i.get(1.0,'end').strip())

print("singles now has {}".format(single_questions))

print("Need to add: {} at list {}".format(single_questions, n))
print ("popping: {} from list {}".format(all_questions[n], n))
all_questions[n] = single_questions
all_questions.pop(n)
print ("now list has {}".format(all_questions))
all_questions.insert(n, single_questions)

print ("\nafter list")
for i in range(len(all_questions)):
    print ("list # {}".format(i))
    for x in all_questions[i]:
        print ("\titem: {}".format(x))
n+=1
clear()
Incrementer()


# Labels
Quest_Label = Label(root, text='Question', font=('Helvetica',15))
Quest_Label.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=x, pady=y)
Ans_Label = Label(root, text='Answer', font=('Helvetica',15))
Ans_Label.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=x, pady=y)
Hint_Label = Label(root, text='Hint', font=('Helvetica',15))
Hint_Label.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=x, pady=y)
# All the Entries or Texts
Quest_Entry = Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12),height=3,bg='light blue', 
fg='black')
Quest_Entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=1, padx=x, pady=y)
Ans_Entry = Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12),height=3,bg='light blue', 
fg='black')
Ans_Entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=2, padx=x, pady=y)
Hint_Entry = Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12),height=3,bg='light blue', 
fg='black')
Hint_Entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=3, padx=x, pady=y)
# Buttons
save_next = Button(root, text='Save/Next',bg="light blue",font=('Helvetica', 
12),command=save_next)
save_next.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)

confirm_btn = Button(root, text='edit/confirm saved'
    ,bg="light blue", font=('Helvetica', 12),command=check_confirm)
confirm_btn.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)
confirm = Button(root, text='edit/confirm saved'
    ,bg="light blue", font=('Helvetica', 12),command=save_new_confirm)

# call main loop
root.configure(bg="gray")
root.mainloop()
```

The answer is probably something minor i forgot to do. But any help would be appreciated. i'm only asking because I've been at this for a few hours now.

Comment: is code correctly formated ? I get error - it can't find variable `l` in line 68 (`if i in l`). Maybe you put code with wrong indentions - use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `single_questions.clear()`. It removes elements but it keeps reference to the same place in memory, so both questions was using the same place.

I use `single_questions = []` to create new empty list (and it doesn't have to be global list)

```
import tkinter as tk

# clear all the entries or Text
def clear_entries(event=None):
    for entry in all_entries:
        entry.delete(1.0, 'end')

# saves single questions, call add_to_all_question and clears screen.  
def save_next(event=None):

    # create new empty list 
    new_questions = []

    for entry in all_entries:
        new_questions.append(entry.get(1.0,'end').strip())

    print("appending:", new_questions)
    all_questions.append(new_questions)

    # clear entries
    clear_entries()
    quest_entry.focus()


# first method of button check confirm
def check_confirm(event=None):
    ''' should disappear after initiation and set back to n=0'''
    global n

    print("Confirm btn pressed")
    save_next.configure(state="disabled")

    confirm_btn.grid_forget()
    confirm.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)

    n = 0
    clear_entries()
    incrementer()

# Increment then display the following questions
def incrementer(event=None):
    global n

    root.update_idletasks()

    if n < len(all_questions):
        quest_entry.insert(1.0, all_questions[n][0])
        ans_entry.insert(1.0, all_questions[n][1])
        hint_entry.insert(1.0, all_questions[n][2])

        confirm.configure(text="Save Entry #{}".format(n))
    else:
        quest_entry.insert(1.0, "No more Entries Click \
Main to close course or back to return to options.")

        save_next.configure(state="normal")
        confirm.configure(state="disabled")

# confirm what's being displayed and save new changes
def save_new_confirm(event=None):
    global n

    print("currently editing list index:", n)

    display_list("before list")

    # create empty list for new values    
    new_single = []

    for entry in all_entries:
        new_single.append(entry.get(1.0,'end').strip())

    print("new single:", new_single)

    all_questions[n] = new_single

    print("now list has:", all_questions)

    display_list("\nafter list")

    n += 1
    clear_entries()
    incrementer()

def display_list(text=None):
    if text:
        print(text)

    for data in all_questions:
        print("list #", data)
        for item in data:
            print("\titem:", item)

# --- main ---

n = 0
x = 10
y = 10

all_questions = []

root = tk.Tk()

# Labels
quest_label = tk.Label(root, text='Question', font=('Helvetica',15))
quest_label.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=x, pady=y)

ans_label = tk.Label(root, text='Answer', font=('Helvetica',15))
ans_label.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=x, pady=y)

hint_label = tk.Label(root, text='Hint', font=('Helvetica',15))
hint_label.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=x, pady=y)

# All the Entries or Texts
quest_entry = tk.Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12), height=3, bg='light blue', fg='black')
quest_entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=1, padx=x, pady=y)

ans_entry = tk.Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12), height=3, bg='light blue', fg='black')
ans_entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=2, padx=x, pady=y)

hint_entry = tk.Text(root, font=('Helvetica',12), height=3, bg='light blue', fg='black')
hint_entry.grid(column=1, columnspan=4, row=3, padx=x, pady=y)

all_entries = [quest_entry, ans_entry, hint_entry]

# Buttons
save_next = tk.Button(root, text='Save/Next', bg="light blue", font=('Helvetica',12), command=save_next)
save_next.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)

confirm_btn = tk.Button(root, text='edit/confirm saved', bg="light blue", font=('Helvetica',12), command=check_confirm)
confirm_btn.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=x, pady=y)

confirm = tk.Button(root, text='edit/confirm saved', bg="light blue", font=('Helvetica',12), command=save_new_confirm)

# call main loop
root.configure(bg="gray")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You figured it out. Thank you so much for taking the time.  i got stuck for so long i began to think it would be the end of my project. It makes so much sense that single_question would be referencing the previous items in it's list if i were programming in java/c. You see i got used to python doing all the low level things so i barely think about what's pointing where, it's kind of why i love python. The fact that it would change not just the second but all following edits should have opened a light bulb. I can't thank you enough, Have a great weekend.